# How to correctly change channel name in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm into coding a discord bot with discord.js. I have to change the name of a channel for some features.
But I got some issues. So I decided to write a very simple code, for make tests.

This is the code :

```js
client.channels.fetch(config.logConnectChannel).then(chan => {

    chan.setName("grfpjihder").then(console.log(chan.name));

});
```

My channel name is "loading". I expected to see `grfpjihder` (random keys), but when I watch the output in my console, I see `loading`, and the name is not changed on the server.

EDIT: The name as changed 10 minutes after on the server

I also don't have any errors in the console.

Also, the code was working a few days ago, and suddenly it stopped working.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2: After more investigating, I think all the renames take effect but takes a long time to. I think there is a time limitation between name changes.

Comment: Use `.then(() => console.log(chan.name))` as that is supposed to be a callback. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Yes, it works. But now, sometimes I have no output in console, and the name is also not changing. @str